# Generalized likelihood ratio statistic for two binomial distributions

Tags: statistics

This question develops hypothesis tests for the difference between two population proportions.Let X ∼ Binomial(n, p1) and Y ∼ Binomial(m, p2) and suppose X and Y are independent.
The hypotheses to be tested are:
H0 : p1 = p2
HA : p1 < p2 or p1>p2

(a) Find the generalized likelihood ratio statistic Λ for testing H0 vs. HA based on the data X and Y .

I am slightly unsure of the distribution of X-Y. I think that X-Y~Binomial(n-m,p) under the null, but then under the alternative, what would the distribution be? And are there any suggestions on calculating the MLE of X-Y in order to calculate the GLRT

Answer (score 0):

The binomial distributions are only *additive* when $n = m\ ;$ also, subtraction does not yield a binomial distribution. A likelihood estimator of $p_{1}$ is $\frac{X}{n}$ and a likelihood estimator of $p_{2}$ is $\frac{Y}{m}\ .$ To test the hypothesis $p_{1}-p_{2} = 0$ versus the alternative hypothesis $p_{1}-p_{2}\neq0$ you can use the test statistic $$\frac{X}{n}-\frac{Y}{m} \ .$$ If $n$ and $m$ are sufficiently large and $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are not too small (so that $\min(np_{1},n(1-p_{1}))>5$ and $\min(mp_{2},m(1-p_{2}))>5$), then the Central Limit Theorem may be used in the computation of the p-value of a given data-set with which you investigate the null hypothesis.